# Remove Website and Website Group from Order Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

How can I remove **"Main Website"** and **"Main Website Store"** from admin order grid?

I need to have only Store Name example **"Italia"** or **"Asia"** etc

[image]

Comment: Post your code here so anyone can help you

Comment: is the magento default code

Answer (score 1):

Change the grid.php code as like `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`

```
 if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
        'index'     => 'store_id',
        'type'      => 'store',
        'store_view'=> false,
        'display_deleted' => true,
    ));
}
```

also change hrere `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Store.php`

```
function render
```

Comment code

```
/**        foreach ($data as $website) {
        $out .= $website['label'] . '<br/>';
        foreach ($website['children'] as $group) {
            $out .= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 3) . $group['label'] . '<br/>';
            foreach ($group['children'] as $store) {
                $out .= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 6) . $store['label'] . '<br/>';
            }
        }
    }
```

**/

For website

New line should be in render function

```
foreach ($data as $website) { $out .= $website['label'];}
```

As per your requirement you can change this

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way. If someone find a better solution is welcome

add a class to website grid

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
  if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
                $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                    'index'     => 'store_id',
                    'type'      => 'store',
                    'store_view'=> true,
                    'display_deleted' => true,
                    'column_css_class' => 'hidden_custom',
                ));
            }
```

add custom js file to admin

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml

```
<default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><name>custom/adminhtml/custom.js</name><params><![CDATA[data-group="js002"]]></params></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Find and replace text with jquery

> js/custom/adminhtml/custom.js

```
(function ($) {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('.hidden_custom').each(function(){
            $(this).html($(this).html().split("Main Website<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Main Website Store<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;").join(""));
        });
    }, 500);
})(jQuery);
```